# Is server-side EJS safe to expose to end-users?

Tags: node.js, security, express, templating, ejs

I'd like to let end-users edit their own website templates using EJS, but since it seems to use evals and runs on the server, I'm not sure if that exposes a major security problem.

If I'm correct that it's a problem, is there a templating engine that is safe to expose to end-users?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, ejs would probably be a security issue.

The [vm](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) module could be very helpful for you here.

Handlebars or Mustache are pretty popular, and might be a bit easier for a not-developer to understand. Jade is awesome but has the eval issue and is so different from HTML.

I would recommend using Handlebars or Mustache in a Node "vm", with some careful considerations and a execution time limit.